# How to make simple mobx reaction work in sub component

Tags: reactjs, observable, mobx

I miss something in mobx observables and reactions.
I prepared two examples, one of them works, the other does not, I don't understand why.

Example 1 (does not work):

```
@observer class Alert1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.r2 = reaction(
      () => this.props.v1,
      v => console.log("Alert1 reaction trigger",v)
    );
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

@observer class Main extends Component {
  @observable v1 = false;
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Alert1 v1={this.v1} />
        <button onClick={e=>this.v1=!this.v1}>Switch</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In example 1 we just send observable variable in props and create reaction in Alert1 component, but it does not trigger.

Example 2 (works):

```
@observer class Alert2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.r2 = reaction(
      () => this.props.someObj.v1,
      v => console.log("Alert2 reaction trigger",v)
    );
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

@observer class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.someObj = observable({v1:observable(false)});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Alert2 someObj={this.someObj} />
        <button onClick={e=>this.someObj.v1=!this.someObj.v1}>Switch</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

That's almost the same as example 1, but we wrap v1 observable into the other observable. Alert2 reaction works.

The same time if we move reactions from Alert1 and Alert2 components to the Main component's constructor, both reactions works.

Here's jsfiddle example with both components, https://jsfiddle.net/kasheftin/zex0qjvf/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/react.html, in your first example, you are not passing an observable around, but just a plain boolean value (`true` or `false`), so there is nothing for the reaction to react to. In javascript, all *values* are immutable so per definition something that is observable. It are the *properties* that are observable.

In the second example you pass an object with an observable *property*, so that is something that can be reacted to.

Note that creating a [*boxed*](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/boxed.html) observable would also work, as those can be passed around as first class citizens. E.g.: `v1 = observable(false)` and `reaction(() => this.props.v1.get(), ...`

Comment: Ok, of course there's the difference between plain value and object that holds it's previous state so in `get` it may compare and trigger some actions. But in my example https://jsfiddle.net/kasheftin/zex0qjvf/1/ there's also r1 reaction in Main class that's based on `this.v1` and this reaction works. But why? Isn't `this.v1` a plain boolean value in Main class?

Comment: because `v1` is there an observable _property_ of `this`. Unlike In the other component where props is just a normal, non-observable object. Did you check the first link? It is about which values you "dot" into. Its not about the values but the props. `this.v1` is a different _property_ then `this.props.v1` in the child component, even though it is the same _value_